# Android - ContentProvider.rawQuery throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm getting familiar with programming Android and ContectProviders. I have created the code (in testing purposes) to check reading/writing to database

This is the code TestProvider.java

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;

public class TestProvider extends ContentProvider
{
    private static final String DBNAME = "testdb";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_MAIN = "CREATE TABLE if not exists test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT)";
    private MainDatabaseHelper helper;

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate()
    {
        helper = new MainDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
    {
        return helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM test", null);
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    protected static final class MainDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        MainDatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_MAIN);
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO test (word) VALUES ('AAA')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO test (word) VALUES ('BBB')");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And this is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TestProvider provider = new TestProvider();
        Cursor c = provider.query(Uri.parse("content://com.example.testapp.provider/test"), null, null, null, null);
        do
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", String.format("ID:%s / Word:%s", c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id")), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("word"))));
        }
        while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace from logcat:

```
07-30 15:38:25.695: E/Trace(3533): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-30 15:38:26.255: D/AndroidRuntime(3533): Shutting down VM
07-30 15:38:26.305: W/dalvikvm(3533): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at com.example.testapp.TestProvider.query(TestProvider.java:45)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     ... 11 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml (the part with the provider)

```
<provider android:name="com.example.testapp.TestProvider" android:authorities="com.example.testapp.provider" android:exported="false">
</provider>
```

Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: 'java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 15:38:26.345: E/AndroidRuntime(3533):     at com.example.testapp.TestProvider.query(TestProvider.java:45)'. Well which code is on that line?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line. `TestProvider provider = new TestProvider();` You should not instantiate the `ContentProvider` directly but use  `getContentResolver()` from your `Activity`. Android instantiates it for it.

Comment: 'You should instantiate the ContentProvider directly' ??? NOT? Indeed i never saw it instantiated like that but why would that cause for a null pointer? Which one?

Comment: @greenapps thanks for pointing out the typo. Android takes care of call onCreate

Comment: So if you instantiate the class yourself onCreate is not called? So `helper ` would be zero then. So one could easily call onCreate self. Wouldn't the provider work then?

Comment: Would you do it with an Activity? @greenapps

Comment: Oh. It looked nice to me testing it in this way. But it was not my idea. Nor testing a content provider in the same app itself with getContentResolver. I have to investigate. Quite interesting all. Today i was implementing a content provider and had to edit, compile and change two apps for it. Would be less work if all can be done within one app. So i like the idea.

Comment: Well i tested the new MyContentProvider(). Called the onCreate() which is necessarry with mines and could do `query()`. Called `()`. and opned an inputstream from the returned file descriptor. Alll worked nearly normal. Nice.Had to add some "/"'s combining uri and path. I think it's better to ujust use getContentResolver().

Comment: if you do that, you probably don't need a `ContentProvider`. For your purposes the SQLiteOpenHelper is enough

Comment: Mines  is not to share a database but to read and write files from internal memory to other apps. Yes i need one but the possibility to test the provider within the same app is nice. I just tested in the same app with getContentProvider() and it works all very well. Could have saved me time if I knew before.

Comment: @Blackbelt, What if I have a few content providers? Which will be called in the line getContentResolver.query(...)?